# Debug version SEGFAULTs whereas Release version works - is it RVO?

Tags: c++, c++11

We have a template class which owns some `std::unique_ptr`, some of which are `boost::asio`

```
template <class cloud_type,
          bool  keep_alive   = true,
          class socket_type  = asio_http,
          class error_handle = default_error_handler>
class callable
{
    callable() = delete;
    // other stuff here, click the link to see actual code
private:
    // other members, most are unique pointers
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_;
};
```

It has [two constructors](https://github.com/ortelio/noos-api-cpp/blob/0.8.0-dev/noos/cloud/callable.hpp) and we've made a wrapper function which supposedly simplifies things:

```
template <class cloud_type,
          bool  keep_alive   = true,
          class socket_type  = asio_http,
          class error_handle = default_error_handler,
          class ...args,
          typename = 
                typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<cloud_type, 
                                                      cloud_batch>::value, bool>>
callable<cloud_type,keep_alive,socket_type,error_handle> 
    call(typename cloud_type::callback functor,
         args... params)
{
    return callable<cloud_type,
                    keep_alive,
                    socket_type,
                    error_handle>(functor, default_node, params...);
}
```

Two of us have tested this, on Ubuntu 16.04 with G++ 5.9 and Boost 1.58.
When we build a `Release` version (with `-O3`) the application works fine.
When however we build a `Debug` version, the application SEGFAULTs.
The actual error I get is:

```
Thread 1 "human_detection" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000443128 in std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service, std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service> >::get (this=0x120) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:305
305           { return std::get<0>(_M_t); }
```

This seems to originate from:

```
#0  0x0000000000443128 in std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service, std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service> >::get (this=0x120) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:305
#1  0x0000000000441880 in std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service, std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service> >::operator-> (this=0x120) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:298
#2  0x000000000043f2b4 in noos::cloud::callable<noos::cloud::human_detection, false, noos::cloud::asio_http, noos::cloud::default_error_handler>::send (this=0x0, timeout=0) at /home/zuperath/code/noos-api-maria/./noos/cloud/callable.tpl:120
```

Which points to:

```
void callable<cloud_type,
              keep_alive,
              socket_type,
              error_handle
             >::send(unsigned int timeout)
{
    assert(socket_ && query_ && resol_ && io_);
    if (!socket_)
        throw std::runtime_error("socket not set");
    if (!io_ || !query_ || !resol_)
        throw std::runtime_error("io, query or resolver not set");
    object.fill_buffer(boost::ref(*buffer_.get()), endpoint);
    socket_->is_connected() ? 
        socket_->send(*query_.get(), *resol_.get(), timeout, *buffer_.get()) :
        socket_->begin(*query_.get(), *resol_.get(), timeout);
    io_->run();
    io_->reset(); // here !!!
}
```

I'm trying to understand what we're doing wrong, and I'm guessing that `Release` uses RVO, whereas `Debug` makes a copy which results in the above?

When I call the wrapper:

```
auto query = call<human_detection,false>(
                 [&](std::vector<noos::object::human> humans) {
                    std::cout << "Found " << humans.size() << " humans!" << std::endl;
                 }, pic);
```

The error persists during `Debug` whereas if I call the class constructor directly, the SEGFAULT goes away:

```
callable<human_detection,false> query([&](std::vector<noos::object::human> humans) {
                        std::cout << "Found " << humans.size() << " humans!" << std::endl;
                     }, default_node, pic);
```

My fear is that there is an underlying problem with the **resources** of the class (e.g., `boost::asio::io`) which is enabled by making the class copyable.

## EDIT:

I solved the SEGFAULT, it was due to a lambda capturing by reference, a (*this*) which was being released.
However, my original question still remains; why is this happening during DEBUG but not RELEASE?

Comment: You have `this==0` in `callable::send`. Add `assert( this != 0 );` in `callable::send`, run debuger and check call stack deeper.

Comment: @DanielSęk assertion wasn't triggered. I think there is a lingering copy of the object with an invalid/moved `asio::io`

Comment: Somehow you have destroyed `this` pointer. Stack trace above shows `this==0` and latter `this==0x120` for member. This shows that `callable::send` or methods called from it destroyed `this`, or `callable::send` was called with `this==0`. Your stack trace is too shallow but I think that `callable::send` is sometimes called on null pointer.

Comment: @DanielSęk yes that's what I saw too, but I think that the method is being called twice, so I reckon the problem is elsewhere, and the SEFAULT is the symptom of it... Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

There is of course a fundamental problem with copying a `unique_ptr`, it's not possible. That is the point of being **unique**. The compiler enforces this by disabling its copy ctor. And the default copy constructor of `callable` therefore does not exist either.

But it does **look** like your `callable` can be copied. What I suspect is happening is that you **accidentally** wrote a converting constructor:

```
callable::callable(callback functor, platform = default_node);
```

I suspect that your `callable` can be converted to a `callback` and ends up being copied via this route.

As a rule of thumb, constructors callable with one argument (possibly after adding default values) should be `explicit`.

BTW: Your other ctor also has a logical error:

```
template <typename... parameters>
callable(callback functor,
         platform info = default_node,
         parameters... args);
```

Exactly how would this default value be used? It could only be used if a single argument is provided, but then overload resolution kicks in and the first ctor would be selected. That said, it is also a potential one-argument ctor in its current form and should also be `explicit`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I've spotted it and removed the `default_node`. I am not sure I understand though, are you suggesting that I am somehow casting/converting a `callable` to a `callback` somewhere?

Comment: @Ælex: I'm wondering if that is indeed happening in the return statement of `call`

Comment: I am afraid not. This SEGFAULT seems to happen when I invoke the copy constructor. I've explicitly deleted it and construct the callable directly and the segmentation fault goes away. The return type is `callable` not `callback` although I admit the wording I've used is dangerous

Comment: @Ælex: I don't get how you deleting a copy ctor that was already deleted due to `unique_ptr` members can make a difference. (?!)

Comment: Not just deleting it, but not using it either. When I do not delete it, isn't it created by the compiler? Or do implicit move semantics use a move operator? I am under the impression that I have two copies of the same object, one with a valid io service and one which has been moved or invalidated.

Comment: To be honest I don't know why this is happening, all I am changing is returning by value, or calling the constructor directly, which is why I am so puzzled

Comment: @Ælex: Good point about move, considering `unique_ptr` _can_ be moved.  But the default copy ctor for a class is implicitly deleted if any member of that class has a deleted copy ctor. Logical - the default copy ctor does a memberwise copy.